# desc limit 50 equivalent in Core Data / NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, core-data, limit

I'm working on an iPhone and I'm using Core Data as my store.

What I'd like to do is list the top 50 entities in descending order by their height.

I'm struggling to find out the syntax for the predicate.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

First, go to the [NSFetchRequest class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html).

Use the sort descriptor to your fetch request :

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

And use the fetchLimit property

```
[request setFetchLimit:50];
```

Comment: From a performance point of view fetchLimit will improve perf only if the store type is SQL, otherwise it will simply do a limit-less fetch and 'discard' the remaining entries. [ https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/fetchLimit ]